# Multi-charcter special names

Tags: cobol

I just created a `CLASS` under the `SPECIAL-NAMES` paragraph that contains more than one character as criteria:

```
SPECIAL-NAMES.
   CLASS TEST-CLASS IS SPACES, LOW-VALUES,
                       "#TT#", "#AA#", "#BB#",
                       "#ET#", "#CA#", "#DB#".
```

What will happen if I do a compare?

Example:

If the following string "#TT#ThisIsATest" is in a variable called `TEST-VAR`

```
IF TESTVAR(1:4) IS TEST-CLASS AND
   TESTVAR  IS NOT TEST-CLASS
   do logic
END-IF
```

I need to know if the first 4 characters match the class. THEN I need to see if there are any other characters (with the exception of the first 4) that are not part of the class.

Will using this class in this way work?

Comment: I believe the literals in the `CLASS` clause of the `SPECIAL-NAMES` paragraph must be single bytes.  Use an 88-level instead.

Comment: @cschneid is correct. A CLASS condition is a condition applied to each byte of a field. Therefore, the members which establish the clash must be one byte long. Pro-rata that statement for multi-byte characters definitions (NATIONAL), but that doesn't help you. An 88-level is the correct way to go. Out of interest, since it is the second recent question with "#xx#', what are those to do with?

Comment: Reading more of your question, I now see why you want to do that. I think. Leaving aside the spaces/low-values, are you trying to say "it must start with a known pattern like this, and then the same known pattern must not appear in the rest of the field"?

Comment: We are using them as delimiters we tell us where data ends and starts. I saw the other question earlier today. I am assuming that user works in the same shop as me because it is a very specific set of delimiters.

Comment: @BillWoodger almost. I want the first 4 characters to match my pattern then ensure that there are no other characters in the PIC X field as it is a big field

Comment: taking time to think about this, I think I way over complicated it. I could just use an 88 level as mentioned above with all of the values I want to compare and then compare that against the first 4 characters of TESTVAR. After that I can check TESTVAR(5:) against spaces and low-values

Comment: You can use a level 88 for both `TESTVAR(1:4)` (with the delimiters) and an level 88 for the rest with spaces/values :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just freehand, but I think you get the idea.

```
01  WORK-AREAS.
    05  TEST-VAR-DLIM-TEST PIC X(004).
        88  TEST-VAR-IS-DLIM VALUES
            SPACES 
            LOW-VALUES
            "#TT#" 
            "#AA#" 
            "#BB#"  
            "#ET#" 
            "#CA#" 
            "#DB#".

MOVE TEST-VAR(1:4) TO TEST-VAR-DLIM-TEST
IF TEST-VAR-IS-DLIM
    ...
END-IF
```